# TabView Label doesn't appear while the background color doesn't fill the entire screen

Tags: swiftui, tabview

This is my reproducible code.
Problems: There is no error in my code but I can't find my TabView Label. The background was declared with .ignoresSafeArea(.all) but still doesn't fill the entire screen.

```
 import SwiftUI

 struct LibraryView: View {


var allColors: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        ForEach(allColors, id: \.self) { color in
            BookSubView(bColor: color)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("BOOK")
                        .foregroundColor(color)
                    Image(systemName: "book")
                }
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page)
 }
 }

struct BookSubView: View {
var bColor: Color
var body: some View {
    LinearGradient(colors: [bColor, Color.white], startPoint: .top, 
 endPoint: .bottom).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
}
}
```

Comment: In the page style TabView does not show tab items.

Comment: fixed both problems by removing the .page except now I can't scroll like a PageView now. Is there a solution for this or this is the limit?

Comment: that's the limit. but you can implement your own TabView with dragGesture

Answer (score 0):

Use a Label inside of the `.tabItem` modifier

```swift
BookSubView(bColor: color)
    .tabItem {
        // There are probably modifiers for Label you can use to customize to your needs
        Label("Book", systemImage: "book")
    }
```

Comment: hmm did not work.

Comment: Make sure you're setting up your TabView similar to what the documentation shows: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/tabitem(_:)